# Segfault when accessing array member of class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, segmentation-fault

There are classes Field and Cell in my program and a few classes inherited from Cell. Main function works with Field, which has an array member containing pointers to cells of different classes. The cells are created in one method and I get Segfault when trying to access them in another methods. I feel that there must be a wrong array creation but have no ideas how to fix it. I tried to change array of pointers just to array of cells but got errors even in earlier stages of program.

To avoid putting here too much code: in main function first field is created as `Field myfield;` and then called functions for it: SetName, SetSize, CreateCells. Then I try to draw `ConsoleDraw(&myfield);` a field with next function:

```
void ConsoleDraw(Field *f)
{
    Cell* cell;

    for (int i=0; i<f->GetHeight(); i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<f->GetWidth(); j++)
            std::cout << f->GetCell(i,j)->GetType();

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Here is code for classes:
Field.h:

```
class Field
{
public:
    //some methods
    void ChangeCell(int i, int j, int type);
    void CreateCells();
    Cell* GetCell(int i, int j);

private:
    //some variables
    Cell*** cells;
};
```

Field.cpp:

```
void Field::CreateCells()
{
    cells = new Cell**[height];
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        cells[i] = new Cell*[width];

        for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
            ChangeCell(i,j,0);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
        cells[i][j]->SetNeighb();//operating with variables of single cell
}

void Field::ChangeCell(int i, int j, int type)
{
    if (cells[i][j]) delete cells[i][j];

    switch (type)
    {
        case 0:
            cells[i][j] = new Cell(0);
            break;
        case 1:
            cells[i][j] = new Cell(1);
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            cells[i][j] = new MovingCell;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
        {
            cells[i][j] = new CreatingCell;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
        {
            cells[i][j] = new KillingCell;
            }
            break;
        case 5:
        {
            cells[i][j] = new DyingCell;
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (type<10)
            {
                cells[i][j] = new DyingCell;
                cells[i][j]->SetChar(type-4);
            }
            else
            {
                cells[i][j] = new MovingCell;
                GetCell(i,j)->SetChar(type-10);
            }
    }

    cells[i][j]->SetCoordinates(j,i);
    cells[i][j]->SetOwner(this);
}

Cell* Field::GetCell(int i, int j)
{
    return cells[i][j];       //Here I got an error. 
}
```

I think there is no need in posting Cell class as all problems appear in operating with Field. Thank you in advance for any ideas of initialising that array correctly.

Comment: `MovingCell mcell; cells[i][j] = &mcell;` This makes `cells[i][j]` point to a local variable that is destroyed immediately afterwards. Voila - instant dangling pointer.

Comment: Another problem: `new Cell*[width]` creates an uninitialized array containing random garbage. But `ChangeCell` assumes the array contains `NULL` or valid pointers. Make it `new Cell*[width]()` (note a pair of parentheses), see if it helps; this causes array elements to be initialized to `NULL`

Comment: I tried to add parentheses but it didn't cause any changes.

Comment: By the way, couldn't it be the same problem with local variable for the whole array in CreateCells method?

Comment: What is this "local variable for the whole array" of which you speak? I don't see anything in `CreateCells` that could be reasonably described this way.

Comment: I mean that I'm creating array in CreateCells. When I'm accessing its members in the same method everything is OK, but when i"m trying the same access in GetCell method it fails.

Comment: Your program, with obvious additions to get it to compile, [compiles and runs for me](http://rextester.com/ESGN46655). The problem is therefore in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @Tami `if (cells[i][j]) delete cells[i][j];`  There is no need to check for NULL before issuing a `delete`.  Second, you could eliminate two levels of "stars" by using `std::vector<std::vector<Cell *>>` instead of `Cell***`, thus eliminating all those calls to `new[]` in the `CreateCell` function by just saying `Cell.resize(height, std::vector<Cell*>(width));`.  Last, we don't know what the values of `i` and `j` are in your call to `GetCell`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Values of i and j are set in ConsoleDraw (the first part of posted code).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for help I'll try to search for problems in other parts of code.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you were right. Finally I found the place where changed copy of myfield instead of myfield itself. Thanks, without your comments it could take me a lot more time to look in that part of code!

Answer (score 1):

The line `if (cells[i][j]) delete cells[i][j];` assumes that all cells have been allocated with `new`, but there are many cases in the switch statement below where cells are not allocated with `new` but rather point to shared locations. This looks unclean to me and can for sure cause segfaults.

Next error:
You are assigning pointers to temporary objects in the default clause in the switch statement in `ChangeCell`. Any access to them will cause segfaults sooner or later. Any call to `delete` on them will cause segfaults.

Comment: I repaired that things in switch. Thank you, it could cause further problems. But this error is still appearing in the same place, as there were created only cells of Cell type.